# Algorithm consulting: Check conditions in a square

Tags: algorithm, loops, if-statement

Suppose I have a image that looks like

```
x x x x
x x x x
x x x x
```

Dimensions might change, but just give a rough idea about this.

I am curious if there is an algorithm that will help me quickly check if the current point I am looking at is a corner / points on one of the 4 sides / within the square itself, as well as helping me check all points around the point I am currently looking at.

My current approach is like writing a few helper functions that separately check if the current coordinate is a corner / points on one of the 4 sides / within the square itself? And within each helper function, I use several loops to check all the neighbor points around the point I am currently looking at. But I feel like this approach is extremely ineffective, I believe there must exists a more advanced way to do this, can anyone help me if you have encountered this kind of question before?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Largely you are correct, but there should be no need to use loops. You can make your functions efficient by using some index calculations and using direct access to 1-dimensional array.

Imagine that your image is stored in a 1-dimensional array D. The image is of `size (m,n)`. Hence the array will have a size of `m x n`. Each data point will have its ID as the index to the array D.

To access neighbors of ID = a, use the following offsets:
`a-1, a+1` for left and right neighbors
`a-m, a+m` for bottom and top neighbors
`a-m+1, a-m-1, a+m+1, a+m-1` for diagonal neighbors

After every offset you need to check for the following:

1. is the neighbor index out of bound for the array D?
2. does the neighbor index wrap around the x-bounds i.e. assert that

`abs((neighbor_id % m)-(a%m)) <= 1` , else `neighbor_id` is not my neighbor.

Of course, the second test assumes that your image is large enough (perhaps `m > 3`).

Comment: Yes I agree with you for direct index accessing, I just feel like for the inside points, there are like 8 directions I need to consider, which I think it's still a low productive way to achieve this, I am just not sure if there is some implementation that can quickly achieve this.